# how to use firestore wherefield method and adding document that collection to another collection

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working a project to use shops. My structure data:

[image]

My code snippet

```
//current user sign in here and uid "VjZfKF1zmrV00C9VeTZxRmogybA2"
let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
let db = Firestore.firestore()
db.collection("Blah").whereField("users", isEqualTo: currentUser?.uid).collection("otherPath").document().addDocument
```

I want to add data to use currentuser uid and if it is matching "Blah" inside documents then add that targeting document other collection.

`.adddocumets` or `.setData` it isn't allowed to firestore, so how can i figure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to send a query and an update statement to Firestore in one go. You will instead have to:

1. Execute a query to determine all documents that need to be updated.
2. Loop over the results of that query in your application code.
3. Update each document in turn inside that loop.

In addition, since `users` is an array field, you'll want to [use the `array-contains` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) to match the correct documents.

Comment: Thank you mrs frank but in app i need to create document match result admin user when sign-in admin user create normal user then code update field new users array when normal user sign-in it is searching all document if it is matching one of them then access the child collection if you have alternative structure data can you share me

Comment: I have no idea what you mean there @ayhnhakn, but this is really the way to accomplish what you wrote in the pseudo-code in your question. Did you try to implement the solution I described? What happened when you did that? Was there any error message?